# Execute line of code when length of list changes Python

Tags: python, streamlit

I am trying to show a certain piece of text when the list length is greater than one.

Initially when the streamlit app is run there are no files in the uploaded images list so I dont want to show the Uploaded Images text but when a person uploads images I want to show the "Uploaded Images :" text.

How do you listen to the length of a list and execute code according to its change.

My Code:

```
uploaded_files = st.file_uploader(
    "Choose samples to upload...", accept_multiple_files=True)

image_list = []
image_captions = []

#ignore this function
def add_border(input_image, border, color=0):
    img = Image.open(input_image)
    if isinstance(border, int) or isinstance(border, tuple):
        bimg = ImageOps.expand(img, border=border, fill=color)
        return bimg
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Border is not an integer or tuple!')


for uploaded_file in uploaded_files:
    image = add_border(uploaded_file, border=10, color='white')
    image_list.append(image)
    image_captions.append(uploaded_file.name)

if len(image_list) > 1:
    st.write("Uploaded Images :")


st.image(image_list, width=125)
```

Comment: There is no built-in way to do this afaik. You'd need to do something like provide your own helper function/class that appends to the list, and also calls any registered listeners. Or you could maybe do something like subclass `list`, then modify the `append` method to call listeners (although that's a bit hacky).

Comment: Is this code inside a function?

Comment: @AndrewGiannoulis No its not inside a function.

Comment: Here is my idea: sINCE THE `image_list` will contain as many images as the ones in `uploaded_files` you can simply do this: 

```
count = 0
for n, uploaded_file in enumerate(uploaded_files):
         count += 1
         # rest of ur code
print("Uploaded Images:")
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate seems a bit too complicated.

Comment: Well, how complicated it needs to be depends on how robust of a system you want. If you want to listen to list changes, I believe you'll need to come up with your own system to do that. It could be as simple as a function that you call instead of `append`, or as complicated as a modified subclass.

Comment: Check my answer, and tell me if this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my idea: since the `image_list` will contain as many images as the ones in uploaded_files you can simply do this:

```
count = 0 
for n, uploaded_file in enumerate(uploaded_files): 
   count += 1 
   # rest of ur code 

print("Uploaded Images:")
```